# state is getting changed to unexpected value, todos.map is not a function,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using react with redux for my application, I have state as array of objects, in reducer for adding new element in an array the entire state is getting changed to 4 instead of showing new element along with old ones and also giving me error "todos.map is not a function".

My State

```
export const todos = [
  {
    id: "1",
    item: "Buy Milk"
  },
];
```

reducer

```
export const reducer = (state = todos, action) => {
  let newTodos;
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      newTodos = state;
      newTodos = newTodos.push(action.payload);
      return newTodos;

    case DELETE_TODO:
      break;

    case UPDATE_TODO:
      break;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

action.payload(ADD_TODO) in redux dev tool

```
type(pin): "ADD_TODO"
payload(pin)
   id(pin): "870f7b60-5267-11eb-85d2-cbd5e33df548"
   item(pin): "ghgh"
```

After dispatching action getting error "todos.map is not a function" and state is getting changed to

```
(pin): 4
```

Comment: thats because you are not gettig array as a response so .map doesnt mean .. can you log your newTodos and action.payload and also new todos after that

Comment: Just remove the assignment here `newTodos = `newTodos.push(action.payload);, as push will return the length of array, you're changing the array to number

Comment: Thanks ArazShamsaddinlouy and @Naren, I will keep a note of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` returns [the length of the new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value), not the array itself. Instead you need to create a new array without mutating the original:

```
case ADD_TODO:
      return [...state, action.payload];
```

Answer (score 1):

You mutate state and then assign state to the wrong value in add todoe:

```
[].push({}) === 1;
```

try this instead:

```
return [...state, action.payload]
```